# Convert or cast object to string

Tags: swift

how can i convert any object type to a string?

```
let single_result = results[i]
var result = ""
result = single_result.valueForKey("Level")
```

now i get the error: could not assign a value of type any object to a value of type string.

and if i cast it:

```
result = single_result.valueForKey("Level") as! String
```

i get the error: 
Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x103215cf0) to 'NSString' (0x1036a68e0).

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: of what type is `single_result.valueForKey(“Level”)` Have you tried using `String(single_result.valueForKey(“Level”))`

Comment: What is results of type?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't cast any random value to a string. A force cast (`as!`) will fail if the object can't be cast to a string.

If you know it will always contain an NSNumber then you need to add code that converts the NSNumber to a string. This code should work:

```
if let result_number = single_result.valueForKey("Level") as? NSNumber
{
  let result_string = "\(result_number)"
}
```

If the object returned for the "Level" key can be different object types then you'll need to write more flexible code to deal with those other possible types.

Swift arrays and dictionaries are normally typed, which makes this kind of thing cleaner.

I'd say that @AirSpeedVelocity's answer (European or African?) is the best. Use the built-in `toString` function. It sounds like it works on ANY Swift type.

### EDIT:

In Swift 3, the answer appears to have changed. Now, you want to use the String initializer

```
init(describing:)
```

Or, to use the code from the question:

```
result = single_result.valueForKey("Level")
let resultString = String(describing: result)
```

Note that usually you don't want valueForKey. That is a KVO method that will only work on NSObjects. Assuming single_result is a Dictionary, you probably want this syntax instead:

```
result = single_result["Level"]
```

Comment: Or you can use result_number.stringValue

Comment: You can just use `toString` directly on the value without casting it.

Answer (score 29):

[This is the documentation for the String initializer provided here.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2427941-init)

```
let s = String(describing: <AnyObject>)
```

Nothing else is needed.  This works for a diverse range of objects.

Comment: This looks like the start of a useful answer, but it ended up in the review queues because it lacked enough explanation. Please edit the answer to add some more information.

Comment: Is that long enough?

Comment: I get error "No exact matches in call to initializer"

Comment: @Curtis, sorry for the super late response, did you figure this out? What object were you passing to the initializer?

Answer (score 7):

The `toString` function accepts any type and will always produce a string.

If it’s a Swift type that implements the `Printable` protocol, or has overridden `NSObject`’s description property, you’ll get whatever the `.description` property returns.  In the case of `NSNumber`, you’ll get a string representation of the number.

If it hasn’t, you’ll get a fairly unhelpful string of the class name plus the memory address.  But most standard classes, including `NSNumber`, will produce something sensible.

```
import Foundation

class X: NSObject {
    override var description: String {
        return "Blah"
    }
}

let x: AnyObject = X()
toString(x)  // return "Blah"
"\(x)"  // does the same thing but IMO is less clear

struct S: Printable {
    var description: String {
        return "asdf"
    }
}

// doesn't matter if it's an Any or AnyObject
let s: Any = S()
toString(s) // reuturns "asdf"

let n = NSNumber(double: 123.45)
toString(n)    // returns "123.45"
n.stringValue  // also works, but is specific to NSNumber
```

(p.s. always use `toString` rather than testing for `Printable`.  For one thing, `String` doesn’t conform to `Printable`...)

Comment: So is string interpolation just calling `toString`?

Comment: I didn't know that toString was implemented in all Swift classes. Thanks for that. (Voted)

Comment: Note that toString was removed in Swift 3. use `String(describing:)` instead

Answer (score 6):

`toString()` doesn't seem to exist in Swift 3 anymore.

Looks like there's a failable initializer that will return the passed in value's `description`.

`init?(_ description: String)`

Docs here https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1540435-init