# Parse/Swift Beginner: How to change label on Parse query

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm making an account page and need to change my IBOutlet "header" to be the user's first name from the "firstName" col of the "_User" class. I can't seem to get the objectId portion to work as it obviously needs to change for each user. Anyway, here's what I'm working with:

```
import Parse
import UIKit
import ParseUI
import Bolts

@IBOutlet weak var header: UILabel!
var user = PFObject(className: "_User")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(user.objectId) {
        (nameAgain: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            header.text = nameAgain.objectForKey("firstName")! as! String
        } else {
            println("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which user are you trying to read? You should use the PFUser class rather than PFObject when dealing with the user class. `PFUser.currentUser` will give you the currently logged in user. Generally you don't have to work to much with objectIds - you just use the objects

Comment: @Paulw11 Would you mind giving an example please? I'd appreciate it so much

Comment: Have you worked through the Parse tutorials?  I highly recommend you do so.  What you have is basically gibberish.

Comment: Yes I have. I have just been having a lot of problems with query because I can only find Obj-C for it. An example would help very much!

Comment: I would strongly advise that you learn at least some Objective-C if you intend to develop for iOS as it will help you when you find example code - converting is normally pretty trivial.  Secondly I can't really provide an example as it isn't clear what you are trying to do.  Nowhere in your code do you identify the specific instance of `PFUser` you are trying to update; you have just created an empty user.  Are you trying to work with the current user?

Comment: You're right. I'm still beginning so I'm working on my Objective-C whenever I can! I'm using the current user, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is get the name of the currently logged in user, you can just use

```
if let firstName = PFUser.currentUser()?["firstName"] as? String {
    header.text=firstName
}
```

`PFUser.currentUser()` returns the `PFUser` object (a subclass of `PFOBject`).  You can then simply index via the column to get the value

Comment: Thanks so much. I am doing the same thing with a float for the amount of credit the account has. I saved a col "payCurr" as type number with a value of 0.03 in it. I wrote:

          if let payDB = PFUser.currentUser()?["payCurr"] as? String {
              paid.text = payDB
          }
Yet it still won't display. Why is this?

Comment: Because a number isn't a string, so the `as? string` will fail and return nil

Comment: Should I save the value in Parse as a String for this purpose or is there a way I can convert the value to a String for Xcode?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280003/convert-or-cast-object-to-string/30280075#30280075

Answer (score 0):

Is difficult to understand how you want to get the name of your user, as per your code:

```
    var user = PFObject(className: "_User") //You create a var user of PFObject
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(user.objectId) {  //Now you are trying to use, at this point you have no users in you var user
            (nameAgain: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil { 
                header.text = nameAgain.objectForKey("firstName")! as! String
            } else {
                println("Error")
            }
        }
    }
```

I will add here some suggestions:

This functions query for all user in the Users table in Parse

```
func userQuery(){
    var query = PFUser.query()
    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        for object in objects!{
            let user = object as! PFUser
            println(user.username!)
        }
    })
}
```

This Login a specific user:

```
func loginUser(){
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("User1", password: "Password1") {
        (user:PFUser?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            println("user login")
        } else {
            println("error login user - \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

And this creates a new user:

```
func createUser(){
    var user = PFUser()
    user.username = "Test5"
    user.password = "Test5"
    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (sucess: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            println("user created")
        } else {
            println("error creating user - \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps you!

Comment: What is your "user.objectId"if you already have the user why are you querying it again?

Comment: @IcaroNZ Parse completion blocks always execute on the main thread.

Comment: All I need is the string "firstName" from the "_User" class and have been having difficulty getting it -- no such problem getting the user's username, though, so Parse is properly configured. If anyone could show me what the code to get the user's firstName would be, I would GLADLY give best answer.

Comment: @IcaroNZ The userQuery() function worked for me! How can I modify it to only grab the value of the firstName col for the currentUser?

Comment: You don't need to query the current user, you can just use "PFUser.currentUser()?.username" but your user has to be logged